# Are there exactly three physically relevant operators that commute with $H$ for helium?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, pauli-exclusion-principle

I am thinking about something I learnt as an undergraduate. In the section on identical particles (page 212) of Griffiths book on quantum mechanics he speaks of helium and says that:

> The excited states of helium consist of one electron in the hydrogenic
>   ground state, and the other in an excited state
>   $\psi_{100}\psi_{nlm}$.

My interest is regarding the quantum numbers. And that he concludes there are precisely three. My feeling is that this is a consequence of the Pauli exclusion principle. But [this thread](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/518635/97775) explains that the Pauli exclusion principle is the observation that a slater determinant is zero if two columns in the determinant are equal. For the elements of the periodic table, it is not the case — as Hartree-Fock shows. Therefore, I see no reason to believe that the Pauli exclusion principle applies. This makes me wonder how we can know that these are precisely the quantum numbers of helium, for example.

Is there a deeper theorem that still ensures this, or is this experimental?

---

Edit:
I have found out the following: To say that $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ is a quantum number of $\psi$, is to say that there there is a hermitian operator that commutes with $H$ and we denote the indices of the eigenvalues of the commuting operator by $k$. We can have multiple quantum numbers if several operators commute with $H$. Because if $K$ is a hilbert space, $H,L$ are normal on $K$ and $[H,L] = 0$, there is a basis  $\{e_k\}_{k=1}^\infty$ for $K$ such that $e_k$ is an eigenvector of $H$ and $K$ for each $k \in \mathbb{N}$. In the case that there are multiple operators that commute, there are multiple quantum numbers as a consequence.

In the case of hydrogen, both $L_z,L^2$ commute with $H$ ($H$ always commutes with itself) so there are eigenvalues $\{\varepsilon_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$, $\{\lambda_l\}_{l=1}^\infty$ and $\{\mu_m\}_{m=1}^\infty$ such that
$$
L_z e_k = \mu_m e_k, \qquad L^2 e_k = \lambda_l e_k, \qquad H e_k = \varepsilon_n e_k.
$$
Therefore the notation $\psi_{nlm}$ is used to indicate that when one of the operators $H,L^2,L_z$ act on $\psi_{nlm}$, we get the values $\varepsilon_n, \lambda_l,\mu_m$.

The question therefore reduces to: Are there exactly three physically relevant operators that commute with $H$ for helium?

Comment: "For the elements of the periodic table, it is not the case — as Hartree-Fock shows" $-$ I have no idea what you mean by this, but it definitely doesn't sound like you understood the thread that you linked here.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty There is no nontrivial Hartree-Fock solution for an element in the periodic table, so there is little evidence that a slater determinant solves the time-independent Schrödinger equation for elements of the periodic table. Now that you understand what I mean, would you like to provide an answer to the question? I believe a complete set of commuting observables provides the answer.

Comment: I am indeed currently writing an answer, but if that type of hostile tone is going to be your only response then I'm pretty tempted to drop it and go do something else instead. We do not owe you our time, you know.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty If it is a good answer, please provide it. I am thankful for your time.

Comment: @ Mikkel if that was an attempt to drop the hostile tone, some friendly feedback -- that attempt failed pretty badly. If you're truly thankful for the time others spend on your questions, then show it.

Comment: I had to give your comment an upvote

Answer (score 0):

I don't have that book at hand so I assume you are treating the helium simply as two independent electrons in a suitable (coulombian, or with spin orbit, or whatever effect you are including) potential. The hamiltonian then is 
$$ \hat H_{He} =\hat H_0 \otimes \mathbb{1} +  \mathbb{1} \otimes \hat H_0  \qquad \qquad (1)
$$
where $\hat H_0=\hat P^2/2m_e +\hat V$.
$\hat H_{He}$ acts on two-electrons states, and you will surely recognize that its eigenvectors are of the form  $\psi_{nlm} \otimes\psi_{n'l'm'}$, with $\psi_{nlm}$ being an eigenvector of $\hat H_0$.
The states where a single electron is excited will then be given by  $\psi_{100}\otimes\psi_{nlm}$, suitably antisymmetrized.  The reason you have $n,l,m$ as quantum numbers is the decomposition (1) of the hamiltonian. Eigenstates of $\hat H_{He}$ are build from the ones of $\hat  H_0$.

Answer (score 0):

The Pauli exclusion principle is irrelevant here.

As Griffiths points out at the beginning of the section, this part of the text is presenting the broadest-strokes heuristics and it's doing some *terrible* approximations in order to get the overall structure of the problem across. In particular, this section of the text disregards the electron-electron repulsion, so he goes from
$$
H
=
\left\{-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\nabla^2_1 - \frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{2e^2}{r_1}\right\}
+
\left\{-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\nabla^2_2 - \frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{2e^2}{r_2}\right\}
+
\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{e^2}{|\mathbf r_1-\mathbf r_2|}
$$
to just
$$
H_\text{non-interacting}
=
H_1+H_2
=
\left\{-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\nabla^2_1 - \frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{2e^2}{r_1}\right\}
+
\left\{-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\nabla^2_2 - \frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{2e^2}{r_2}\right\}
.
$$
As the text of the section points out, this is a *terrible* approximation, and it over-estimates the ionization potential by around 50%. Nevertheless, it is still useful as a starting ground since $H_1$ and $H_2$ are hydrogenic (so we know all of their eigenstates analytically), so we can use them as building block to start approximating the true eigenstates.

In this section, Griffiths isn't doing any of that yet. He is still working on a broadest-brushstrokes-possible basis, and he is only talking about the eigenstates of $H_\text{non-interacting}$ for now. Since these are non-interacting electrons, it just boils down to two copies of the hydrogenic problem, so when Griffiths says

> The excited states of helium consist of one electron in the hydrogenic ground state, and the other in an excited state $\psi_{100}\psi_{nlm}$

he is (for now) only talking about $H_\text{non-interacting}$. Later on in the book (in section 7.2 in my copy), he revisits helium to get a better approximation for the hydrogen atom, to show how the hydrogenic-eigenstate ingredients he's using here can be modified to provide a better approximation for the hydrogen atom. The same can be done with the excited states, and the procedure will yield eigenstates of the form $\tilde\psi_{100} \tilde\psi_{nlm}$, with modified $\tilde\psi_{nlm}$s, that form better approximations to the orbitals, though, as noted in the previous thread, this is only ever an approximation $-$ if you want full spectroscopic accuracy, you need to do a numerical diagonalization that yields a superposition of multiple spin-orbit Slater determinants.

Comment: It's important to note that all of the components to the answer to the question are *stated explicitly in the very same page in Griffiths as the quote you brought up*. Please take a minute to consider carefully whether you're really reading the text carefully enough that it'd be appropriate to use hostile (and to be honest, rather petulant) comments like "I see no reason to believe that the Pauli exclusion principle applies". Of course it applies $-$ it's a law of nature and it *always* applies.